# How to deal with the size of images and filters if we use Covolutional LSTM + Conv2D?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, lstm, tensorflow2.0

I am working on Convolutional LSTM + convolutional neural Network. Instead of getting my data in image format i have been given flattened images matrix which is [10000x784].

Means 10000 images of size 28x28

Considering one image size is 28x28, i am trying the following for CLSTM

My model is:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Reshape((None,28, 28,1 ), input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                   input_shape=(None, 28, 28, 1),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(2500, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

but i am getting the subjected error. What can i do to make ndims=5?

Answer (score 0):

First try to print input and output details of your model:- (eg:)o/p will be like this - Input to marks model: [{'name': 'input', 'index': 451, 'shape': array([ 1, 160, 160, 3], dtype=int32), 'dtype': , 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}] Output of marks model: [{'name': 'embeddings', 'index': 450, 'shape': array([ 1, 512], dtype=int32), 'dtype': , 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}]

once you will get details, according to the details you will have to assign the values.

Answer (score 0):

5 dimensions of ndim=5 are [Batch, TimeSteps, ImageWidth, ImageHeight, ImageChannel]
By default all conv Layers will have the [Batch] dimension, even if you did not mention, it will be 1, Time step is what you have to give.

If you are wrapping your conv2d layer with timedistributed layer, it means you are going to apply the convolution in parallel to multiple images in a sequence (best suited for frames extracted from videos, rather than independent images)

So TimeSteps indicate how many such images you want to give as input

Batch is usually the Number of images to be process as a batch after which your loss will be calculate and this is a part of any conv2d layer

So be sure how many images you want to pass as time steps and how many such time steps as a batch

if you have 1000 images and you want to split them as just 100 in a batch, that means your BatchSize will be 100 and you will get 10 of such batches to complete your epoch.

within that 100 image in batch, you can any number of images (that make sense to you) to pass and convolute at a time as single time step( may be 10, may be 20)

So you need to decide this and reshape your matrix as
(100 X 10 x 72 x 72 x imgChannel) or whatever numbers you pick for batch and timeSteps

```
>>> inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10, 72, 72, 3))
>>> conv_2d_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))
>>> outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(conv_2d_layer)(inputs)
>>> outputs.shape
TensorShape([None, 10, 72, 72, 64])
```

Refer:[Keras Time Distributed Layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/time_distributed/)